# Getting Contents of PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I'm new to C#, long time C++ programmer, im just wondering once initalising a propertygrid using .selectedObjects. Is there a way to get contents of the current values in the propertygrid.

Ben

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you're setting SelectedObject then you have access to the object that the PropertyGrid is modifying, no?

Answer (score 0):

PropertyGrid doesn't expose its internals to the consumer.

However, .Net lets you perform "Refelction" to examine the structure (and execute parts of) code, including class properties.

[Here](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_tutorial_reflection.html) is an article that covers the basics of reflection.  You can actually see more of the internals with reflection than what the property grid displays.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all the properties of the object in the grid, using Reflection based in the object's type.

```
object o = PropertyGrid.SelectedObject;
Type t = o.GetType();  // We will work on type "t"
List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
members.AddRange(t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);  // Get the public instance properties list
foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
{
    Type type = null;
    object value = null;
    PropertyInfo pi = (member as PropertyInfo);
    type = pi.PropertyType;
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CollectionBase)))
        continue;  // Sorry
    if (pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotSerializedAttribute), true).GetLength(0) > 0)
        continue;
    if (!pi.CanRead || !pi.CanWrite)
        continue;
    value = pi.GetValue(o, null);
    // TODO Print out, or save the "value"
}
```